# Inserting and displaying special characters in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, escaping

I am creating small messaging module and I'm trying to accurately store the data they type in.

Currently I strip HTML tags from the input and the add `htmlentities` to escape special characters...

```
$message = strip_tags($_POST['input']);
$message = htmlentities($message, ENT_QUOTES);
$message = $Database->escape($message);
```

escape is simply `mysqli_real_escape_string`

I then use the following to then try and parse and display the data again...

```
$message = str_replace('\r\n', '<br>', $message); 
$message = str_replace('\n', '<br>', $message); 
$message = str_replace('\r', '<br>', $message);
```

I am having trouble trying to display `\` (backslash) as it shows two instead of one (even though one was written)

Comment: Show off some more code.

Comment: @TimWolla Added the first half to the code, thats really all I got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double-quote `"` characters instead of single-quote `'` characters around escape sequences.

```
$message = str_replace("\r\n", '<br>', $message); 
$message = str_replace("\n", '<br>', $message); 
$message = str_replace("\r", '<br>', $message);
```

In PHP, literal strings are interpreted differently when encased in double-quotes.

Quoting the [PHP manual page on Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape
>   sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur
>   in single quoted strings.

So `echo '\n'` will literally output a backslash followed by **n**, whereas `echo "\n"` will output a Unix line-feed character.

Comment: Could ya help out a 49er? (Shameless request for an upvote — or whiskey.)

Answer (score 0):

I use [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/html_entity_decode) whenever I  want to display  special characters that are being converted using htmlentities.

try:

```
$message = html_entity_decode($message);
```